# Reducing boiler plate code (getters and setters) in a DTO modelling class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to remove the getters and setters boilerplate code below but I am unsure of how to do so. I have a DTO class to model the JSON column `questionVariables` in my entity.

DTO

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class QuestionVariables implements Serializable  {

    private ScreenOptions screenOptions;
    private QuestionOptions questionOptions;

    public ScreenOptions getScreenOptions() {
        return this.screenOptions;
    }

    public void setScreenOptions(ScreenOptions screenOptions) {
        this.screenOptions = screenOptions;
    }

    public static class ScreenOptions implements Serializable {

        private boolean isSkippable;

        public boolean getisSkippable() {
            return this.isSkippable;
        }

        public void setisSkippable(boolean isSkippable) {
            this.isSkippable = isSkippable;
        }
    }

    public static class QuestionOptions implements Serializable {

    }
}
```

Entity

```
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;

@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class) })
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")

@Data
public class Question {

    @JsonSerialize
    @JsonDeserialize
    @Nullable
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json", nullable = true)
    private QuestionVariables questionVariables;
}
```

I've tried using Lombok @Getter and @Setter annotations but it doesnt work. I get the error below

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.io.Serializable;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class QuestionVariables implements Serializable  {

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class ScreenOptions implements Serializable {
        private boolean isSkippable;
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class QuestionOptions implements Serializable {

    }
}
```

The error

```
[ERROR] 2021-04-07 10:17:52,484 com.nana.elp.utils.exceptions.DefaultExceptionHandlerAdvice http-nio-8000-exec-2 - Error Code {unknown}, Error Message : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given string value: {
  "screenOptions" : {
    "isSkippable": true
  }
} cannot be transformed to Json object; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given string value: {
  "screenOptions" : {
    "isSkippable": true
  }
} cannot be transformed to Json object
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used lombok much but I think you're supposed to use the @Getter and @Setter annotations on the property, not the class

```
public class ScreenOptions {
    @Getter @Setter private boolean isSkippable = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class QuestionVariables implements Serializable  
{
    private ScreenOptions screenOptions;
    private QuestionOptions questionOptions;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public static class ScreenOptions implements Serializable 
{
    private boolean isSkippable;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public static class QuestionOptions implements Serializable 
{
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `@JsonDeserialize` to the `isSkippable` property for it work

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class QuestionVariables implements Serializable  {

    @Getter @Setter private ScreenOptions screenOptions;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class ScreenOptions implements Serializable {
        @JsonDeserialize private boolean isSkippable;
    }
}
```